# Update one table depending on info from others

Tags: php, mysql

I want to give points to an user, depending on a bet the user submit.

I have a table called `vm_table` which works as a standings:

```
|uid   |name   |points |
|207   |Daniel |2      |
|208   |Jack   |0      |
```

Then each of theese users have its own table called `vm_207`, `vm_208`, and so on - so vm_(the user id)..

```
|id |bet |
|1  |2-1 |
|2  |2-2 |
```

and

```
|id |bet |
|1  |3-0 |
|2  |1-2 |
```

At last I have a table with some matches, called `vm_matches`:

```
|id  |home  |away     |res |
|1   |Spain |England  |NULL|
|2   |France|Russia   |NULL|
```

Okay, so what I want now, is when I write the correct score in `vm_matches`, it changes the point in `vm_table` depending on the user-table-bet. So let's say Spain - England is 2-1. So it should give 5 point to user-id 207, because `vm_207` says 2-1 in match 1. So now the `vm_table` should look like this:

```
|uid   |name   |points |
|207   |Daniel |7      |
|208   |Jack   |0      |
```

First of all, is that even possible? I used a case before, so when I write the result, the `UPDATE`-query would give points, depending on the bets. But at that time, every bet was in the same table, but now they are in different tables.

I know it's a little bit confussing, but I hope you can help me.

Comment: It's really not a good idea to create as much table as users

Comment: Your database design is not good.  Instead of storing each user's metadata in a separate table, you should store all user data in the same table.  Adding a new table for each new user won't scale at all.

Comment: @DanielE. No, I guess not. But I don't know what else to do.. I have 48 matches - it's going to be a gigantic table if every user should be in the same table :/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so you think I should make a table with 48 x number of users rows and then connect them to the user-id fx?

Comment: Let's say I have just 10 users, it's 480 rows. Isn't that way to much?

Comment: Not even close.  Even 480K rows is possible without too much trouble.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh cool .. I just wrote in here sometime, where I was told I had way to much, but maybe that was columns? Can't remember. Well, I'll try that then :) Makes my work a lot easier.

Comment: 480 columns would be to much but for rows you may have huge table with 1 Millions rows ;)

Comment: Cool ! Thank you guys! :D